# What version of VBScript is used in Power Automate Desktop?

Tags: vbscript, power-automate-desktop

Within Power Automate Desktop, I can create an action to run a VBScript.
For example, if I have created a variable `CurrentDate` with the
`Get current date and time` action, then the following script in
a VBScript action will generate output in a text variable in PAD:

```
VBTest = 3
WScript.Echo VBTest
WScript.Echo "%CurrentDate%"
WScript.Echo "Year %CurrentDate.Year%"&" DOW %CurrentDate.DayOfWeek%"
```

Output captured in variable:

```
3
12/5/21 12:00:00 AM
Year 2021 DOW Sunday
```

But what is the version of the scripting engine used, and how can I get
more info about what is available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Documentation about VBScript (which is no longer actively updated
by Microsoft, it cannot even by found in the [product life cycle
search](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/products/?terms=VBScript)) can be found under [previous versions of Internet Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/scripting-articles/d1wf56tt(v=vs.84)).

Running the following VBScript in Power Automate Desktop 2.14 reveals
the scripting engine "VBScript Version 5.8.16384".

```
Function GetScriptEngineInfo
   Dim s
   s = ""   ' Build string with necessary info.
   s = ScriptEngine & " Version "
   s = s & ScriptEngineMajorVersion & "."
   s = s & ScriptEngineMinorVersion & "."
   s = s & ScriptEngineBuildVersion 
   GetScriptEngineInfo = s   ' Return the results.
End Function
WScript.Echo GetScriptEngineInfo
```